# batch items in list with spaces

Tags: batch-file, arraylist

I'm new to batch and trying to write a program that automatically removes some old printers on the company's pc's. The following part of the program should take a list of printers and iterate trough the list to check which printers are connected on the current pc.

```bash
@echo off
set printerList=printer1 printer2 printer3 

(   for %%i in (%printerList%) do (
        echo %%i
        set file=C:\Users\praktikant\Documents\cfptp.txt
        rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xg /n"\\CompanyPrinterServer\%%i" /f"%file%" /q
        if exist "%file%" (
            echo "%time% : %%i is connected, removing...">>C:\Users\praktikant\Documents\log.txt 
            del cfptp.txt
        ) else (
            echo "%time% : %%i is not connected">>C:\Users\praktikant\Documents\log.txt
        )))

if exist "C:\Users\praktikant\Documents\cfptp.txt" (
    del cfptp.txt 
    echo "file deleted"
) else (
    echo "no file"
)
```

The problem now is that some if the printers have spaces in their name and the list is seperated by spaces...
I dont really have a clue, but I think id just be something with correct placement of "" or a parameter i can pass..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Double-quote your printer names, (or at least those which have spaces, or other poison characters), e.g. ```set printerList=printer1 "printer 2" printer3```. Then change ```"\\CompanyPrinterServer\%%i"``` to ```"\\CompanyPrinterServer\%%~i"```, and optionally any `echo`es with `%%i` to `echo`es with `%%~i`. Additionally you need to move the ```set file=C:\Users\praktikant\Documents\cfptp.txt``` line up to the line below ```set printerList=printer1 "printer 2" printer3```, unless you want to have to deal with delayed expansion.